# IMetadataExchange could not be found

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to build two webservices with WCF (VS2010).
One webservice runs fine, but when i added a second webservice, then i got the following error:

> The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list
>   of contracts implemented by the service {0}. Add a
>   ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the
>   ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

The second webservice is basically a copy of the first one. So i have no clue why i'm getting this error and how to solve this. Anyone any idea what the problem might be?

Here is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfEmguCV1.Service1Behavior" name="WcfEmguCV1.EvalService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfEmguCV1.IEvalService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfEmguCV1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WcfEmguCV1.Image">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfEmguCV1.IIMage">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfEmguCV1/Service2/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfEmguCV1.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,
         set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
         set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment
         to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="WcfEmguCV1.Service2Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,
         set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
         set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment
         to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. First of all, i was adding new data to the App.config through "Edit WCF Configuration" option. (Right click on the App.config file and you should see that option).

Since the first webservice config was already by default there, i had to add a new one. So i tried to enter the exact same data. But some things can't be added through that method.

Because when i took a closer look at my XML file i noticed i was missing this for the 2nd webservice:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WcfEmguCV1.Service1Behavior" ...>
```

So all i had to do was to add that to the 2nd node of 'service'.

behaviorConfiguration="WcfEmguCV1.Service2Behavior"